# Loop is not doing what expected

Tags: objective-c, loops

I'm studying Obj-C and now I'm not understand why my loop isn't work how it should. I know a way i could achieve result with single `while` loop, but i want to do this through `do while` and can't figure out whats going wrong.

What i want is, to show integer called triangularNumber for integers 5,10,15.. and so on. There is what i've tried:

```
for (int i=1; i<51; i++){


            int triangularNumber;

            do {
                triangularNumber = i * (i+1)/2;


                NSLog(@"Trianglular number is %i", triangularNumber);

            }
            while (i%5 == 0);

        }
```

It produce odd results:
1) Condition of i%5==0 is not met, it output 1,3,6,10 then infinite numbers of 15
2) It create an infinite loop

Please tell me, what is wrong in that code and how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: You're not changing `i` in the `do` block. Either it will never loop, or it will loop forever.

Comment: @Mat, how to fix it?

Comment: Well you fix the logic. Why do you have that do/while loop in there at all? When is it supposed to loop or not?

Comment: @Mat, it suppose to do calculation only when i is 5,10,15 and so on.. That why i check for  while (i%5 == 0).

Comment: But that doesn't make sense. If `i%5==0` is true the first time the while condition is checked, you understand that the `do` block will be re-executed, right? And if that happens, at the end of that second execution, `i%5==0` will still be true because you don't change `i`. So the do block will be run again. And again. And again... `do/while` is a looping construct. You don't need a looping construct. So don't use one.

Comment: @Mat, thank you! Now i see why its not working! Thank for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of do while loop within for loop, use if to check whether a number is divisible by 5 or not.

If you want to do it with do while loop, you could do the following:

```
int i = 5;
int triangularNumber;
do {
    triangularNumber = i * (i+1)/2;
    NSLog(@"Trianglular number is %i", triangularNumber);
    i += 5;
} while (i < 51);
```

Reason your code is not working:

- Within your do while loop, if i say is 5, then you will end up running in infinite loop as you will satisfy your do while loop's condition which is `i%5==0`
- You just need numbers like 5, 10, 15.. so it's just matter of one loop. Now loop starts with 1 till 50, and you are picky in the sense you just need one element of 5, hence to be picky you could use if condition which says print if and only if my i is multiple of 5.
- Do while will always enter into loop and will execute it once. So for 1 it will enter and do calculation for triangularNumber as 1 * 2 /2 = 1 and hence your output 1 and checks condition post printing is 1 divisible by 5, no then it comes out and increments i to 2 and follows same routine as above.

Comment: I know how to achieve result but i want to know, how to fix current code (i want to understand do-while routine)

Comment: Its not needed. Are you saying you just want to do it by do while loop? If that's the case i would suggest you remove your outer for loop.

Comment: Yes i only need to do this doing do-while loop, and want to understand why my code is not working and produce odd results.

Comment: Thank you almas now i understand the logic!